# Where to start?

Tags: education, self-learning, learning

I want to learn Mathematics but I don't know where to start. Sometimes I really get frustrated as I am a Software Engineering graduate (currently working) and I feel like I don't know anything about it (not even arithmetic). I was considered a good student by my teachers, but I feel like I have forgotten everything I had learnt in school and college. The problem with me now is that whatever I learn, I forget, I mean if I learn something now, after few days I face problems with the same thing until I revise it. I just want to know if I am doing it wrong, is there a sequential and effective way to start from scratch and go on..

Comment: 1. What level of math have you formally studied, whether or not you feel you remember it? 2. You clearly have no issues forgetting how to add, I assume. What's the earliest point that you have trouble remembering properly?

Comment: Calculus is maximum that I was exposed to while I had studied Linear Algebra and Statistics as well during my university. The last Mathematics related subject that I had studied was Statistics, about 4 years ago. I don't seem to remember it. I also believe I don't have issues with addition. But I seem to have problems with what comes after it.

Comment: What are your interests? To keep motivated, it's helpful to hang your learning over a narrative... Like how does general relativity work? Or, how can I write my own compiler?

Comment: Like learning any foreign language, your best shot to making true progress learning it is through immersion. The trick is figuring out how to incorporate enough math into your daily routine, and in such a way that you remain engaged and it doesn't become a chore. My advice is to hang out here, read the daily questions whether you understand them or not, and see how much of a birdseye view of mathematics you can pick up.

Comment: @dls It was about 10 years ago when I got interested in computers and video games, I wanted to design and develop my own video game, but now as I am already a Software Engineering graduate, there are far many things that I want to do. Over the time I have realized I need more and more Mathematics for everything that I want to do.

Comment: I'm a proponent of picking a very specific topic with which you're already familiar. This way you already understand what problem the mathematics solves, even if you don't understand the details of the mathematics. If you want to learn about video games, maybe start with computer graphics. This will give you a chance to brush up on your linear algebra. As for as basic algebra, use a textbook or Khan Academy to fill in gaps as you discover them.

Comment: @dls I agree on your notion of picking up a topic and then sticking to it, but the thing is I want to start it all over because I think that is going to be the best option. The problem is it goes circular, I choose a topic, when I study it, it needs background of another topic, when I study that topic, I need background of another topic and on and on, that is one reason I want to start it all over rather than going back in reverse.

Comment: @aghashamim I have the same exact question down to being an SE grad.  As some time has elapsed, I’m curious if you found a good answer